# make cloned repository as a github fork?

Tags: git, github

There is a origin github repository A

I cloned A into my local computer.
Then I created a github repository B

I changed the local's remote origin from A to B and pushed it.
Now B is a copy of A, but I didn't use the `fork` button to create the B.

Can I make B a fork of A?

I tried setting B's upstream to A. But it doesn't make B a fork of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make B a fork of A. You could:

- Start over and actually fork A. Or
- Give your local a second remote (traditionally called `upstream`) and use it to fetch new material from A periodically and thus incorporate and communicate it to B.